# Xcode beta 6 first view controller

Tags: swift, xcode6

When i try to build a half complete app which consist of 2 view controllers and simulator only shows the second view controller and ignores the first. I also get a warning ( yellow triangle ) saying something about undefined entry points

Comment: actual error message?

Comment: Unsupported Configuration     Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier

Answer (score 1):

It's cause you did not set an entry point for your app select ViewController that you want to be showing first and check is initial view controller in the attribute inspector